# Blender Geometry Nodes - remove double instance and end pieces

Tags: geometry, nodes, blender

I'm very new to blender and started testing out geometry nodes following a tutorial.
(Donuts and Gummies)

I am now attempting a small project to polish my skills.
I want to have only one instance of the traverse on the long shaft every n times. Currently, I have two instances in the middle and 4 at the ends. (see image below)

My objectives are:

1. Get one instance every n times on the shaft
2. Remove the end pieces completely.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my first issue by merging the edges like so

[image]

Still need assistance on the 2nd issue, please.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my second issue was fixed using the Trim Curve node.

I had to do some calculations to plugin the values, but that was the easy part.

[image]

[image]

Hope someone finds this useful.